# Twitch PRIVMSG not being sent to other channels

Tags: c#, bots, streamwriter, irc, twitch

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvFhz.png)

Conosle.WriteLine("It worked!") It's being executed on all Twitch.tv/channels

But ...

PRIVMSG #Twitch.tv/channel works only on my own channel which is twitch.tv/traps_are_not_gay_baka

I mean I can read messages from whatever channel I put into the channel string but PRIVMSGs only work with my own channel and when I switch it to something like Twitch.tv/bakoni which is random channel I found and used for testing PRIVMSGs just do not arrive.

Why is that?

EDIT: (the code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
namespace chatrig
{
    class chatrig
    {
        static String ip = "irc.twitch.tv";
        static Int32 port = 6667;

        static String username = "traps_are_not_gay_baka";
        static String password = "oauth:hokzuz***********ebkv5gnb";

        static String clientID = "2lubvv5***********3f2m8orz24c";

        static String channel = "bakoni";

        static TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(ip, port);

        static StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
        static StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            writer.WriteLine("PASS " + password);

            writer.Flush();

            writer.WriteLine("NICK " + username);

            writer.Flush();

            writer.WriteLine("USER " + username + " 8 * :" + username);

            writer.Flush();

            writer.WriteLine("JOIN #" + channel);

            writer.Flush();

            while (true)
            {
                var message = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(message);

                if (message.Contains("yandYo"))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("PRIVMSG #" + channel + " :" + "w" + "\r\n");

                    writer.Flush();

                    Console.WriteLine("It worked!");
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question - the image is unusable. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I included it just now

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact of not waiting for proper responses from the IRC server, the format for an outgoing message is

```
writer.WriteLine( string.Format( ":{0}!{0}@{0}.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #{1} :{2}", username, channel, message ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for providing me with that information I just switched the code with yours but the result is still: [link](https://i.imgur.com/PH8mNKS.png)

Comment: Are you doing a join on that channel you want to send to? You can only send messages to channels you've joined.

Comment: Yes I use the following line: " writer.WriteLine("JOIN #" + channel); "

Comment: hmmm, everything looks ok

Comment: I have no idea why it is not working with channels other than mine

Comment: I tried your code and substituted in my own credentials and tried it in both my channel and another channel, it worked without errors.

Comment: I made a video to show you my exact steps btw failed to hide oauth but I don't think it's that big of a deal anyway here it is: [link](https://youtu.be/Koh7AXR0sok)

Comment: nah nvm I mistaken the clientID for the oauth yea still stuck sorry about that :D

Comment: glad you got it figured out, no worries :D

Comment: nah I didn't I mean I thought I was using oauth:hokzuz***********ebkv5gnb instead of the actual oauth:hokzuz(randomchars)ebkv5gnb but in fact I was looking at the client ID I'm still stuck unfortunately

Comment: oh, my bad. have you verified the account? can you normally talk in other chats?

Comment: you mean e-mail verification ? on my twitch account ? yes

Comment: yes, your twitch account. can you view and chat normally with a browser? I ask because the code works for me, i'm wondering if its your account.

Comment: yes I verified my e-mail months ago and yea it is my account and yea I can chat normally from Chrome but I don't use other browsers